# angularjs service with $http.post not entering both success or error callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-fullstack

I have an meanjs app generated from angular-fullstack yeoman generator

and in it an auth angular service like this -

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
    .factory('Auth', function Auth($location, $rootScope, $http, User, $cookieStore, $q) {
        var currentUser = {};
        if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
            currentUser = User.get();
        }

        return {

            login: function (user, callback) {
                var cb = callback || angular.noop;
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.post('/auth/local', {
                    email: user.email,
                    password: user.password
                }).
                    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $cookieStore.put('token', data.token);
                        currentUser = User.get();
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                        return cb();
                    }).
                    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        this.logout();
                        deferred.reject(data);
                        return cb(data);
                    }.bind(this));

                return deferred.promise;
            },

            /**
             * Delete access token and user info
             *
             * @param  {Function}
             */
            logout: function () {
                $cookieStore.remove('token');
                currentUser = {};
            },

            getToken: function () {
                return $cookieStore.get('token');
            }
        };
    });
```

So, basically on my signin page controller I am doing something like this -

```
$scope.login = function () {
        $scope.authError = null;
        // Try to login
        Auth.login({
            email: $scope.user.email,
            password: $scope.user.password
        })
            .then(function (data) {
                // Logged in, redirect to home
                console.log(data, 'gee');
                $state.go('app.dashboard-v1');
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                $scope.authError = 'Email or Password not right';
            });
    };
```

So, I have tried to put `console.log('something');` statement in both the success and the error callbacks in my service but It is not getting printed in any case. I am sending a `POST http://localhost:9000/auth/local 405 (Method Not Allowed)` for my incorrect credentials that is a 405 status code, and 200 for correct credentials. So, should I change my client side service code or controller code or server side status code to fix this ?

[UPDATE]
I have tried the answer suggested by @Bastien
and changed my controller code to -

```
Auth.login({
            email: $scope.user.email,
            password: $scope.user.password
        })
            .then(function (data) {
                // Logged in, redirect to home
                $state.go('app.dashboard-v1');
                toaster.pop('success','message','message');
                console.log(data, 'gee');
            },function(err){
                $scope.authError = 'Email or Password not right';
                console.log('err');
            })
```

But I am not getting the any message on the browser console, also I noticed I am getting one more error in browser console only whenever I am entering wrong credentials, it is as follows -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at angular.js:9408
    at processQueue (angular.js:13248)
    at angular.js:13264
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:14466)
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14282)
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14571)
    at done (angular.js:9698)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:9888)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:9829)
```

is this of any relevance ?

Comment: I think the issue is that your `success` and `error` functions are returning `angular.noop` and therefore `Auth.login` is not returning the promise to your controller

Comment: what change should i do then? as this was the boilerplate code we got from the angular-fullstack generator and I am not sure what other functionality would it break if I removed the `angular.noop`

Comment: On second thought, `angular.noop` is in a different context than your `Auth.login` and it shouldn't matter. Try by passing `function (error)` as the 2nd parameter to `then()` as @Bastien suggested in his answer

Comment: I have tried the function(err) and updated the question just now with another error that I found in my browser console

Comment: now it seems like your response doesn't return any data. for now try changing your error handler in `Auth.login` to `error(function(response){console.log(response)})` and see what the response object contains.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
Auth.login({
    email: $scope.user.email,
    password: $scope.user.password
})
.then(function (data) {
    // Logged in, redirect to home
    console.log(data, 'gee');
    $state.go('app.dashboard-v1');
},
function(error){ //2nd function to handle the error (!= 200)
    $scope.authError = 'Email or Password not right';
});
```

The method "then" has multiple parameters: The first is for the success handler, the second is for the error handler

Comment: little bit of explanation is always good and helps everyone to understand.

Comment: Sorry: The method "then" has multiple parameters: The first is for the success handler, the second is for the error handler

Comment: Sorry: I tried the way you suggested but I haven't got it working yet. i have updated the question once more, can you please have a look at it @Navoneel